# Java - appending text in JTextArea in JScrollPane stops the program

Tags: java, swing

There are: JTextArea log, JScrollPane scroll. Here's the creating Scroll function:

```
    public void createLog(){

    log = new JTextArea();
    log.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(log);
    scroll.setLocation(400,5);
    scroll.setSize(400,400);
    add(scroll);
    }
```

It's a code of creating the scrollpane. Here's the function I need to do:

```
    public void setBotx2(int coins, int playcoins){

    int lose = 0, play = playcoins;
    while(coins > playcoins && coins < 2147483647)
    {
        lose++;
        coins -= play;
        if(drawNumberQuickly()%2 == 0)
        {
            coins += play;
            play = playcoins;
            log.append(lose + ". Game won. Coins: " + coins + ". Now playing 
    with: " + play + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            play = playcoins*2;
            log.append(lose + ". Game lost. Coins: " + coins + ". Now 
    playing with: " + play + "\n");
        }               
    }
    log.append("Lost in the " + lose + ". game.");  
    }
```

When I start this function in the application, program stops and cannot be closed. I needed to close it with task manager.  Everything is in a frame, so I didn't add frame.add(..).

Comment: More than sure it's a Threading issue, but for better help sooner post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, so we don't have to guess. And also this will lead to less confusion and more and better answers :)

Comment: There also could be an infinite loop inside `setBotx2` function. It depends on the parameters you pass and the result of `drawNumberQuickly()`.

Comment: Your game logic must be in different thread than gui.

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually I managed to fix the problem. I didn't want to use Threads.. so I added a boolean variable, that is **true** only, when the Button is pressed. When it's true, **while{}** happens. And then this function is also in a loop in my frame. Sounds complicated, but it's the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html).

It shows how to use a `SwingWorker` to publish results. It even use coin flipping in the example.

So modify the working example to use a JTextArea for you updates instead of the text fields.